# Why is the expected file not being deleted?

Tags: plugin-development

Can somebody tell me why this isn't working? I'm trying to get it to create a file in the plugins directory. After I get this working, I'll be trying to get this to create a file in the active theme's directory. Can somebody help me out here?

**EDIT**

I've changed my code, right now it creates the file but it does not input the text 'Testing' into the file even. Is there something I'm missing here?

```
$filename = __FILE__;

register_activation_hook($filename, 'superActivation');
register_deactivation_hook($filename, 'superDeactivation');

global $myFile, $fh, $stringData, $filename, $pluginbase, $full_plugindir;

$myFile = "../wp-content/themes/striking/testFile.php";
$stringData = "Testing\n";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

function superActivation() {
    global $myFile; global $fh; global $stringData; global $filename;
    fwrite($fh, 'test');
    fclose($fh);
}

function superDeactivation() {
   global $myFile;
   if(is_file("$myFile")) {
   unlink("$myFile");
   }
}
```

Comment: Be more explicit about "not working". Is the activation function not run at all, or is the function run but the file isn't created?

Comment: @MathSmath I got it to create the file now, and in the right directory, but now I'm just having a problem with my deactivation hook. It won't delete the file, it says I don't have permission. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jared What are the testFile.txt's permissions? You can use chmod to set permissions on a file right after you create it (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php). It could also be an ownership issue. If the file isn't properly owned, it won't matter what the permissions are. Assuming you're running apache, I find that CHOWNing all my uploaded files to apache:apache usually works for me, as apache is the user that php runs under. But hopefully someone with more premissions/ownership experience can chime in... I only know enough to be dangerous :)

Comment: @MathSmath - the thing is, this is for a client so it needs to all be automated. The project I'm working on started out as a theme, and now I'm making it into a plugin. There's already tons of people who use the theme, which is why I need it all to be automated. Is there any way to do this without having to CHMOD or CHOWN?

Comment: @Jared It can be automated. chmod and chown are both php functions, and you can use 'em right from your function. Check the link I included. But before you do that, I'd try CHMODding and CHOWNing manually to see if that in fact fixes your problem. If it does, just include a chmod/chown step right after your file upload. Know what I mean?

Comment: Well, I got it to write the file and the data that I want it to, but I'm only having problems with deleting the file now. I didn't have to do any CHMODding or anything. Does the PHP function unlink and unset only work for the directory that the script is run from? Because it's not letting me delete the same file I created with fopen. Please help!

Comment: @Jared Now that I think about it though, be careful with chown if this is going to be a publicly distributed plugin. You never know how the server is going to be set up, and which accounts to use. Hopefully a simple chmod will fix things for you.

Comment: `Warning: unlink() [function.unlink]: No error in C:\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxx.php on line 29` and line 29 is just `unlink($myFile);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unlinking, try:

```
function superDeactivation() {
   $myFile = "testFile.txt";
   if(is_file("$myFile")) {
   unlink("$myFile");
   }
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
function superDeactivation() {
   $myFile = "testFile.txt";
   unset($myFile);
   unlink("$myFile");
}
```

Comment: I tried both, but with no luck. The second code, if I remove unlink("$myFile"); and just leave unset($myFile); there, it doesn't give me any errors anymore but it still doesn't delete the file. I'm also having problems getting the php to input data to the file.

Comment: I got this to work and thanks for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: @noeltock if you unset a variable, it cannot be used just after with unlink then the 2nd code cannot work